# Github Actions Organisation node deployment to github pages

Tags: node.js, devops, github-actions

I have been trying to deploy a create-react-app using GitHub actions which deploys the React application to gh-pages and I get the following error when trying to deploy: -

```
Find out more about deployment here:

  bit.ly/CRA-deploy

Cloning into '/home/runner/work/some/some/node_modules/.cache/gh-pages/github.com!***!some.git'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/***/some.git/' not found

Error: The operation was canceled.
```

I have the following node.js.yml

```
name: MasterDeployCI
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - production
      - gh-pages
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [8.x, 10.x, 12.x]
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v1
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    - name: Install Packages
      run: CI=false npm install
    - name: Deploy to GH Pages
      run: |
        git config --global user.email ${{secrets.EMAIL}}
        git config --global user.name ${{secrets.USERNAME}}
        git remote set-url origin https://${{secrets.SECRET}}@github.com/${{secrets.USERNAME}}/some.git
        CI=false npm run deploy
```

I have tried looking through the documentation and google but have been unable to find a solution.

Comment: Is your GitHub project a private repository?

Comment: @cvekaso it's not private on my organization.

Comment: Is the name of your repository ```some```?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Saharadigital/sahara-digital/blob/develop/.github/workflows/node.js.yml#L28

It seems secrets.USERNAME is not exists on repositories secret page. Did you checked?

https://github.com/Saharadigital/sahara-digital/runs/1311779817#step:5:4 this is also shows the same.

Comment: does it need to be something like https://${{secrets.SAHARA}}@github.com/Saharadigital/sahara-digital.git?
I have also added a username to the secrets page

Comment: Yes since ${{secrets.SAHARA}} is going to contain your secret this will work. You don't need to add username as it's public.

Comment: That deployed properly but I still have a white screen on the website.